# Speech Synthesis sounding distorted in Chrome

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I have a function using Speech Synthesis. It works on its own while called onload:

```js
function speak() { 
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(); 
var voices = voices[2]; 
msg.voiceURI = "native"; 
msg.volume = 2; 
msg.rate = 1; 
msg.pitch = 1;
msg.text = "Hello World"; 
msg.lang = "en"; 
speechSyntesis.speak(msg)}
```

But when called in my function which maps an array, with onmouseover, it becomes distorted.

```
if (el.toString === "Kinder.") return "<span class=\"tooltip\"><span onmouseover=\"speak()\">Kinder</span><span class=\"tooltiptext\" >Text</span></span>"
```

It works, but the voice sounds distorted. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Works fine once, then stops working.